# Run subprocess that asks for password and then go back to current shell

Tags: python

I need to run a command that spawns an SSH server, it asks for credentials (password) and then stays running. I need to do some more commands after so I want to run this in a separate process, ask user for password and then back to the main shell to continue with the script. How would I go about doing this?

Here's what I have:

```
cmd = 'command to start the server %s' % (username)
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

Comment: Could you just pass it to the subprocess's stdin, using `.communicate`?

Comment: As an aside: You could switch to SSH public key authentication to facilitate things.

Comment: @scnerd I've tried that with server = subprocess.call(cmd, stdin, subprocess.PIPE, shell=True) and then server.communicate(password). It doesn't work, maybe I'm doing it wrong. It still asks for the password and doesn't open the server in a different shell so I can continue to run other commands

Comment: It might be trying to fetch the password from somewhere besides stdin. For example, does it work if you just try ``echo PASSWORD | ssh ...`` from the terminal? Look into how other people pass passwords into the ssh command programmatically (e.g., from terminal), that might give you the answer to how to do this in your particular situation (e.g., there's probably a command line argument)